# Generate SDK dartdoc

Tags: dart

Is possible to generate the dartdoc from $DART_SDK or from bleeding_edge ?
I tried this with `unittest` :

```
dartdoc bleeding_edge-master/dart/pkg/unittest/lib/unittest.dart
```

And it works, but when I do this `aync`

```
dartdoc bleeding_edge-master/dart/sdk/lib/async/async.dart
```

It fails :

```
library dart.async;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/Applications/dart/dart-sdk/lib/async/async.dart:5:9: Warning: duplicated library name    "dart.async".
library dart.async;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
bleeding_edge-master/dart/sdk/lib/async/deferred_load.dart:40:3: Error: External method     without an implementation.
  external Future<bool> load();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: generation failed: Failed to create mirror system.
```

I want it to play with json doc files in `0` generated directory. How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run vanilla dartdoc on built-in "dart:" core libraries. Since it implicitly reads in those libraries on its own, you get duplicate definition errors.

Instead, there is a separate tool, "apidoc" in the Dart repo that we use to generate the core library docs. It's built on top of dartdoc, but has a few modifications to do some special stuff.

It's run automatically as part of the build process, so if you just clone the Dart repo and run `tools/build.py`, you'll get an `api_docs` directory in the output directory containing the docs.